Azure Stream Analytics Window Agg
how to solve the problem in azure stream analytics using windowing functions



col1
col2
status
flag




Q1
P1
started
1


Q1
P1
connected
1


Q1
P1
ended
0


Q1
P1
completed
0


Q1
P2
started
1


Q1
P2
connected
1


Q1
P2
ended
0


Q1
P2
completed
0


Q2
P3
started
1


Q2
P3
connected
1



O/p:
we need to aggregate columns 1 and 2. If column 3 contains values such as ended or completed, we should consider the corresponding value in column 2 as 0. If column 3 contains values such as started or connected, we should consider the corresponding value in column 2 as 1. Finally, we need to sum the values in column 2 for all rows.



col1
count




Q1
0


Q2
1



I was able to calculate the minimum value at the col2 level using a sliding window. However, when I tried to perform aggregation at the col2 level using a sliding window, it performed a cumulative sum instead.
with min_val as (
select col1, 
col2,
min(flag) as val 
from cte 
group by col1,col2, slidingwindow(day,1))

select col1
,sum(val)
from min_val
group by col1, slidingwindow(day,1) -- This sliding window is doing cummulative sum


You can use TumblingWindow(minute, 1) as an aggregate function to group by the required columns. This will group all the col1, col2 rows and then you can know whether the current group is completed or still in connection.
select col1, 
col2,
GetArrayElement(collect(flag),GetArraylength(collect(flag))-1) as count
from <your_input> 
group by col1,col2, TumblingWindow(minute, 1);

The collect() will collects all the flag rows of the group in the same order. So, if you get the last value in the collect(flag) array, then it will give the status of the current group like below.

